# How to install Harbor behind the Traefik proxy

Tags: docker, harbor

I would like to install Harbor behind Traefik proxy. The problem is, I can not do it with docker-compose because Harbor provides installation script.

The question is, it is still possible to install Harbor behind Traefik proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you can install Harbor behind any proxy, but you must note that Traefik is more then a simple proxy, it is like Load Balancer with some feature that know where your services are.

So depends on your service network architecture, in generally Traefik could not be a problem whether it state in front of Harbor like an Edge Router or a Transparent Proxy. Although it targets to discovery all your services expose by some Orchestrator Solution like Kubernetes and Docker Swarm (Harbor use Compose). You should config it like a "The startup configuration (referred to as the static configuration)":

[Traefik configuration](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/assets/img/static-dynamic-configuration.png)

Finally and sadly I must discourage you to use Harbor behind Traefik proxy is useless, but you can hardly use it.